# Why not pork stock/gravy?

Tags: pork, stock, gravy

Why is it that you make stock (and/or gravy) from a roast chicken or beef or fish, but you don't do the same for pork?

Comment: I've never experienced a fish stock, myself; seems like you'd have to collect quite a few heads and bones to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Fish stock isn't really used much in western cooking but is excellent in things like fish curry. You can use the skin and tails from prawn, crayfish etc. as well as heads and tails from the fish and fish left overs to make it.

Comment: In Sweden where I live, we use fish stock all the time. For soups and sauces

Answer (score 3):

Ham bone soup and red eye gravy are some common preparations (in the southern US, at least) made from pork leftovers. We'll also make sawmill (white) gravy with cooked sausage. It's delicious over biscuits.

Comment: Ham bone soup is delicious!  I make a similar bean soup using pork neck bones.  Pork stock is alive & well at our house!

Comment: Ham or pork stock is fantastic as a base for minestrone soup. It's quite salty which the pasta and beans soak up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If I boil a ham or gammon hock, I'll often use the stock from that to make pea and ham soup.  Its a) delicious b) Cheap and really easy, basically involving adding a bag or 2 of frozen peas and some of the meat from the ham.

Comment: I am cooking that right now. :) I am chucking in a little more veg and tomatoes though. I did let the stock sit over night and I removed most of the fat.

Answer (score 1):

The flavor I think is why you usually don't see many other stocks.

> Beef makes excellent general use stock, but fatty meat such as lamb, pork and oily poultry like duck and goose have too distinctive a flavour.

Quote pulled from [here](http://www.tescorealfood.com/glossary/stocks.html)

I can attest to the lamb stock.  I made a sauce from a lamb leg bone and the flavor was dominated by strong lamb taste.

Comment: This is my favorite sauce, made with lamb neck: http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Herbed-Lamb-Chops-with-Pinot-Noir-Sauce-232874?print=true

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because it is so greasy. But they do use pork as a base for things like baked beans.

Comment: Grease is just fat, and all animals are fatty when you get right down to it.  Generally it's pretty easy to just skim the fat and/or strain it later, but if you've got a *lot* of fat (or blood, as in beef) then often you bring it to a simmer once in plain water to "clean" the bones, then discard the entire pot, and start over again with your mirepoix and so on.